# How to filter a table remove duplicated keys and keep unique value for each key in one table?

Tags: postgresql, query, unique-constraint

The input data and output example as the picture.
I tried to use pandas to filter the data after I try query:
select * from tablename;

is there any better way like only using a SQL query to do this job?
DB:postgresql

[image: input data]

[image: output filtered data]

Comment: Look into `string_agg()`.

Comment: Thank you. it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`STRING_AGG()` examples](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/), as per Laurenz.

Here's how you'd apply it to your table:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    STRING_AGG(class, ',') AS class
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: This one helped.
Thank you.